# KeyBindings not firing in a JComponent

Tags: java, key-bindings

I'm trying to make a paint app and I recently added undo functionality. The undo command works fine as I tested it with a JButton. However, when I attempt to trigger the undo function with CTRL+Z, nothing happens. I've tried using KeyListeners as well, but the key handler events are not being called.

```
public class DrawPad extends JComponent{

    public DrawPad(){
        setDoubleBuffered(false);   //Should the program use a buffer to paint?
        setFocusable(true);         //Allow the JComponent to be focusable
        requestFocusInWindow();     //Ask to be focused

        //KeyEvent.VK_Z fails as well
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control Z"), "undo");
        getActionMap().put("undo", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("test");
                undo();
            }
        });
    }
```

Irrelevant code removed, including the undo function and the graphics aspect of the component.